# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::DatetimeFieldOverflow: ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "25/11/2019 12:46:32.486096")

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm making an app with RoR and I have it up on heroku.

After some modifications that a I did, i can't insert data on my database. Actually not even migrate database.

All data with timestamp trigger an error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::DatetimeFieldOverflow: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range
```

I can't find which modification I made that broke my app and also didn't find a solution. I already tried changing the datestyle to 'ISO, DMA' and 'ISO, MDA'.

This is a command that adds a Banco(Bank) modal to the database followed by its error.

```
$heroku run rails console
Running rails console on ⬢ calm-oasis-62348... up, run.8528 (Free)
Loading production environment (Rails 5.2.3)
irb(main):001:0> a = Banco.new
=> #<Banco id: nil, numero: nil, nome: nil, cmc7: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
irb(main):002:0> a.numero = "x"
=> "x"
irb(main):003:0> a.save
D, [2019-11-25T13:04:15.915725 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.3ms)  BEGIN
D, [2019-11-25T13:04:15.919950 #4] DEBUG -- :   Banco Exists (1.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "bancos" WHERE "bancos"."numero" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["numero", "x"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2019-11-25T13:04:15.922333 #4] DEBUG -- :   Banco Create (1.5ms)  INSERT INTO "bancos" ("numero", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["numero", "x"], ["created_at", "25/11/2019 13:04:15.920210"], ["updated_at", "25/11/2019 13:04:15.920210"]]
D, [2019-11-25T13:04:15.923599 #4] DEBUG -- :    (1.1ms)  ROLLBACK
Traceback (most recent call last):
        1: from (irb):3
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::DatetimeFieldOverflow: ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "25/11/2019 13:04:15.920210")
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
: INSERT INTO "bancos" ("numero", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"
```

My app works normally local

Thanks for help.

Comment: Have you tried add a time_zone to you application.rb?

Answer (score 0):

In some modification I made was created the `/config/initializers/file date_time_formats.rb`.

This file defines how date values are displayed and saved in the database.

My database does not accept dates with the format "dd/mm/yyyy"

I just made the modification

From: `Time::DATE_FORMATS[:default]= '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S'`

To: `Time::DATE_FORMATS[:db]= '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`